# Secure Image Uploading in Servlets

Tags: java, security, image-uploading

I've been looking for a way to filter images that have been uploaded to the server using Java.

Is there a library like [Verot's PHP upload class](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm) that rewrites images to the server to make sure that non-image data (like strings or extraneous binary data) are not included?

I want to do this because the strings could be malicious JavaScript and the binary data could be executable which could be harmful to the server.

Comment: You could always try and read the image via ImageIO. It will create a null image if the supplied data is garbage.

Comment: Thanks but will this work with images that have appended non-image data? It's a valid image but with illegal additions.

Comment: That you would have to test and find out. It may just leave out the appended data, but once again, you have to test to confirm.

Comment: Of course, if the server's image parsing is written in C and has a vulnerability, you've just made things worse. Generally you want to parse the image in an environment where a memory corruption vulnerability is impossible or not that significant, and then server the image from a different domain with different IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

After the file is uploaded check it with this method!

```
public boolean checkIfImageFile(String filename){ 
        boolean isimage=false; 
        try{ 
                BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(new File(filename)); 
                if (bi!=null)isimage=true; 
        }catch(Exception e){ 
                isimage=false; 
        } 
        return isimage; 
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. Though will this work with images with added data? Some images are valid images, they just have non-image data appended. The gifar (gifs with jars in their data) and the some images with the JavaScript put in as metadata.

Comment: Well in that case, just render the BufferedImage to a new one, and [save](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) that new image. That will strip it of any data and you can store it in your preferred format.